# angular trigger changes with $watch vs ng-change, ng-checked, etc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently we could monitor data changes with several ways. We could trigger model changes with `$watch` and we could add directives to elements and bind some actions to it.

It's a little bit confusing in many cases, so I'm curious, which is pro and cons of each variant and when should we use `$watch` binding, and when directives like `ng-change`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Both `$watch` and `ngChange` have totally different usages:

Lets say you have a model defined on a scope:

```
$scope.myModel = [
    {
        "foo":"bar"
    }
];
```

Now if you want to do something whenever any changes happen to `myModel` you would use `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch("myModel", function(newValue, oldValue){
    // do something
});
```

`ngChange` is a directive that would evaluate given expression when user changes the input:

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option for option in options" 
ng-change="myModel=selectedOption"></select>
```

In short, you would normally bind `ngChange` to some HTML element. While `$watch` is for the models.

Comment: but $watch("input", inputChanged, true) will also working and will triggering when you change your input value.

Comment: The difference is that `ng-change` does not evaluate the expression when the value change is coming from the model while `$watch` specifically listens to the model updates.

Comment: So you mean if bind data to model, then add watch listener to that model, and then will change model inside listener - then it will evaluate watch listener once again?

Answer (score 16):

Code of `ngChange` directive:

```
var ngChangeDirective = valueFn({
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    ctrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
      scope.$eval(attr.ngChange);
    });
  }
});
```

Guess what, `ngChange` requires a controller from `ngModel` and executes the bound expression when the view is changed.

So it's like a helper that save you from doing tedious tasks like [$watch 'model' then do stuff].

On performance perspective, you have one less `$watch` expression to worry about.

Comment: Is that last statement true? Is `$viewChangeListeners` not like a `$watch` itself?

Comment: yes it is true, you can refer to this article for more detailed explanation :)
https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/effective-strategies-avoiding-watches-angularjs/

Answer (score 8):

Directives like `ng-change` are used for data-binding to DOM. `$watch` is used in your JS code to listen for changes.

When you need to have the DOM be affected by a change in your scope, or need to have a change in DOM (eg. field selection) affect the scope, you would use a directive.

If you need to trigger JavaScript actions from a change in scope, for example an ajax request, then you would use `$watch` in your controller (or service) to listen for the change.

Comment: but if you bind element to model, like input. then when you change input value - it's automatically change the model field value. And then $watch listener will be triggered and you could implement any logic you want without directing dom manipulation, only interacting with model.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what directives are for. Directives deal with DOM, and your JS code in controllers/services can deal with other things.

Answer (score 2):

If you want two-way data binding, then use `ng-model`. This pushes changes from model to view and from view to model -- two ways. However, if you just want one-way data binding from view to model, then use `ng-change`. If you want simple one way data binding from model to view, you can use an expression `{{ like_this }}`.  But if you want a lot more control over how the model is rendered in the view, or if you want to bind the model to something other than the view, then use a `$watch`.