# How to call AngularJS function from select > option

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to call an AngularJS function from selection:

```
<select ng-model="selection" >
<option onselect="angular.element(this).scope().functionCall('one')">one</option>
<option onselect="angular.element(this).scope().functionCall('two')">two</option>
<option onselect="angular.element(this).scope().functionCall('three')">three</option>
<option onselect="angular.element(this).scope().functionCall('four')">four</option>
</select>
```

However, the function never gets called.

In the controller,

```
$scope.functionCall = function(value){
// do stuff with value
}
```

How can I call the function.

Comment: You need a custom directive.

Comment: Use $scope.$watch in your controller to do something when the selected value changes

Answer (score 34):

It's recommended that you use `ng-change` for that matter, the result may be the same as Cyril's, but the code is more readable and testable, also it is considered a better practice:

Here is a plunker demonstrating it in action:
http://plnkr.co/edit/7GgwN9gr9qPDgAUs7XVx?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.listOfOptions = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

  $scope.selectedItemChanged = function(){
    $scope.calculatedValue = 'You selected number ' + $scope.selectedItem;
  }
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<select ng-options="option for option in listOfOptions" 
        ng-model="selectedItem"
        ng-change="selectedItemChanged()">
</select>
```

Hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting 'undefined' when I am trying to print '$scope.selectedItem' inside the function using console.log

Comment: @A_J Angular looks for an object to retrieve value, then ng-model need to assign to an object. I did and it worked.

Comment: I used this way :
       ng-change="selectedItemChanged( selectedItem )"

Answer (score 2):

A Little bit to add on Cyril's and Fedaykin answers:

HTML code

```
<select ng-options="option for option in listOfOptions" 
    ng-model="selectedItem"
    ng-change="selectedItemChanged()">
```

Controller Code

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.listOfOptions = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

  $scope.selectedItemChanged = function(){
   console.log($scope.selectedItem);
  }
});
```

You will notice that when the select option is changed, a function gets called which will give the you the value of the current selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do :

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="YourController">
    <select ng-model="selection" ng-options="choice for choice in choices"></select>
</div>
```

YourController :

```
$scope.choices = ["first choice", "second choice",...]
$scope.$watch('selection', function(newVal, oldVal){
    switch(newVal){
        case 'first choice':
            [do Some Stuff]
            break;
        case 'second choice':
            [do Some Stuff]
            break;
        default:
            [well, do some stuff]
            break;
    }
}
```

BTW: I decided to put the options in the javascript, but what you did also works.

EDIT : ng-change VS $watch, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007281/angular-trigger-changes-with-watch-vs-ng-change-ng-checked-etc)

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful.

Comment: your ng-options will not populate the select element properly that way... it shoud be `choice for choice in choices`

Comment: And yes your answer feels better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

First, onselect is not a angular keyword, It's a normal javascript keyword

You should use ng-change param in select or use like below..,

In HTML code you have to use like this.,

```
<select ng-model="selection" >
<option onselect="functionCall('one')">one</option>
<option onselect="functionCall('two')">two</option>
<option onselect="functionCall('three')">three</option>
<option onselect="functionCall('four')">four</option>
</select>
```

and in the controller

```
function functionCall(value){
//do stuff with value
}
```