# Is there a way to run an angularjs function if a specific option in a select element is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, function

I have a web form and I was just wondering if there is a way to call an angularjs function when a specific `option` is selected.

Here is some of the code:

```
<select>
  <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
  <option value="Cash" >Cash</option>
  <option value="Credit Card" >Credit Card</option>
</select>
```

I want to run an AngularJS function when `"Credit Card"` is selected.

Unlike in [How to call AngularJS function from select > option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797915/how-to-call-angularjs-function-from-select-option), I want to only run function if `"Credit Card"` is selected!

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I only want to call a function if `"Credit Card` is selected.

Comment: Use ngChage directive: `ng-change="paymentOption === 'Credit Card'" && yourFunction()` where `paymentOption` is ngModel bound to select.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm not completely understanding.  Do you think you could please elaborate? Sorry...

Comment: Something like this `<select ng-change="paymentOption === 'Credit Card' && yourFunction()" ng-model="paymentOption">`

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked!

Comment: @dfsq one thing: what if I wanted to call a different function if `"cash"` is selected. Could I also do that through `ng-change`?

Comment: Of course. Just then it's better to use switch statement in your function. `ng-change="yourFunction()"`