# When to use $watch or ng-change in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

When should I use angular `$watch` functions and when use `ng-change` angularjs directive? To me, they both can do the same.

Are there any differences or usage patterns between them?

Comment: $watch and ng-change does roughly the same thing, but their use cases are different.

Comment: The $watch will check the values (old and new) and compare them every time anything causes the Angular $digest cycle to run. Using ng-change does roughly the same thing, but I believe it is syntactically more correct to use.

Comment: Another question quite similiar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007281/angular-trigger-changes-with-watch-vs-ng-change-ng-checked-etc

Answer (score 92, accepted):

They are not the same, clearly. One is used solely in the controller; the other is a directive on an input element.

But even in their application they differ.

When you use `$watch` the watched expression will be evaluated on every digest cycle, and if there is a change, the handler is invoked.

With `ng-change`, the handler is invoked explicitly in response to an event.

With `$watch`, change can come from anywhere: user action, controller function, service - all will trigger the handler.

With `ng-change`, the change is restricted to a user action on a particular input element.

It is worth to note also that `ng-change` works *only* in combination with `ng-model` - in other words, the `ng-change` expression is evaluated only when `ngModel.$viewValue` (refer to [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) documentation for more info) is changed, which typically happens in response to a user-initiated event.