# fired event when expecific strings are being typed on a ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

Let say a ng-model is being updated when user is typing a input or div contenteditable, if we want to fire an event each time it user types certain strings, like 'I'm writing something' then user types "something" I want to fire an event.

Which is the best way to approach this without having to use a watch?

Comment: Would using ng-change be acceptable?

Comment: probably, I just dont have any idea how to attact this problem

Comment: basically I need to display a datepicker when user types for sample,oct or sep or jan....

Comment: There are two ways to achieve it, `ng-change` and `$watch`, here they discuss about their efficiency and uses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007281/angular-trigger-changes-with-watch-vs-ng-change-ng-checked-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic outline. The regular expression just checks for a few months so you'll have to add them all. For an input field like this:

```
    <input type="text" id="dateval" ng-model="typeddate">
```

In your controller do this:

```
    $scope.typeddate = "";

    $watch('typeddate',function(newVal,oldVal) {
        var re = /jan|feb|mar|apr/i ;
        var res = newVal.match(re);
        if(res != null) {
             // you have a match so do what you need to do
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Following what was said on the comments, you could do something like:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.error = false;
  $scope.changed = function(input) {
    $scope.error = input == 'foo' ? true : false;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p>Don't type 'foo'</p>
  <input type="text" ng-change="changed(input)" ng-model="input" />
  <div ng-show="error">Gezz, you shouldn't</div>
</div>
```