# Debounce a function execution in a watcher (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash, watch, debouncing

I have a watch on `vm.search` variable, which is a ng-model of an input element. When I type something, I want to save it to database with a `delayedSave` function, but I don't want to save everything user types. So i decided to use  lodash `_.debounce` function, but the problem is that this function doesn't work correclty within a `$scope.$watch`. `delayedSave` executes as many times as `$scope.$watch` function.

```
$scope.$watch('vm.search', nv => {
    let savedQuery = _.find(vm.searchQueries, {query: nv});

    if (savedQuery) {
      vm.currentSearchQuery = savedQuery;
    }

    let runDebounce = _.debounce(delayedSave, 1000);

    runDebounce(nv);

});
```

I could set debounce to `$watch`'s callback, but I need to execute the code, I've written below, every time `vm.seach` has changed.

```
let savedQuery = _.find(vm.searchQueries, {query: nv});

if (savedQuery) {
  vm.currentSearchQuery = savedQuery;
}
```

Comment: `ng-model` provides two-way data-binding that comes with a watcher. Your text field can then be: `<input ng-change="your_save_func()" ...`, so you can remove `$watch` completely and just use your "save function" within a controller

Comment: @AlekseySolovey ng-change works the same as ```$scope.$watch```, also I need to execute the first part of the code.

Comment: `ng-change` is used on DOM, whereas `$watch` is like a `$broadcast` listener that detects changes in JS code. Here is a [comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007281/angular-trigger-changes-with-watch-vs-ng-change-ng-checked-etc)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, let me be more concise: ```ng-change``` doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Consider going down the `ng-change` route. Would delaying the change to the model be what your looking for?
`<input ng-model=".. " ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" ng-change="save_func()" />` Your ng-change function and your model will not update until 1 second has passed.

Comment: @alexhuang I've tried earlier to use ```ng-model-options``` with a ```debounce ``` option, but that didn't worked also. However Ori Drori's anwer helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same `runDebounce` method should be called repeatedly for the debounce to work. Since you are recreating the `runDebounce` function on each digest cycle, you're running a different method each time. Since the method is not called again, the debounce timeout passes, and the wrapped method `delayedSaved` is invoked.

Move the creation of the debounced function `runDebounce` out of the `$watch` callback:

```
const runDebounce = _.debounce(delayedSave, 1000);

$scope.$watch('vm.search', nv => {
    const savedQuery = _.find(vm.searchQueries, {query: nv});

    if (savedQuery) {
      vm.currentSearchQuery = savedQuery;
    }

    runDebounce(nv);

});
```